# List Activity not working

Tags: java, android, listactivity

Hey guys I'm a new programmer, I'm trying to make a list menu in Android 2.2 I've tried every tutorial I can find and I keep getting an Instrumental class error When I use debug to try the app on my phone

Heres my Code

```
package com.IrishSign.app;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

String alphabet[] = { "Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd", "Ee", "Ff",};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, 

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alphabet));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String selectedClass = alphabet[position];
    try{
    Class OurClass = Class.forName("com.IrishSign.app." + selectedClass);
    Intent OurIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, OurClass);
    startActivity(OurIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

The List works but when I click on an item it force closes and I get the error on my computer,

P.S: I've always wanted to start coding since I was ten and I'm heading off to college next year and would like to have bit of expierience with Java and android so it would really help me out if you guys could help me out.

Edit Log cat

```
 01-04 19:10:14.608: W/System.err(3931): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:         com.IrishSign.app.Aa
01-04 19:10:14.608: W/System.err(3931):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-04 19:10:14.618: W/System.err(3931):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
01-04 19:10:14.618: W/System.err(3931):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:181)
01-04 19:10:14.618: W/System.err(3931):     at com.IrishSign.app.Menu.onListItemClick(Menu.java:29)
01-04 19:10:14.618: W/System.err(3931):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
01-04 19:10:14.628: W/System.err(3931):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
01-04 19:10:14.628: W/System.err(3931):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
01-04 19:10:14.628: W/System.err(3931):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1849)
01-04 19:10:14.628: W/System.err(3931):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-04 19:10:14.628: W/System.err(3931):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-04 19:10:14.638: W/System.err(3931):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-04 19:10:14.638: W/System.err(3931):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
01-04 19:10:14.638: W/System.err(3931):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 19:10:14.638: W/System.err(3931):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-04 19:10:14.638: W/System.err(3931):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-04 19:10:14.638: W/System.err(3931):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-04 19:10:14.648: W/System.err(3931):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 19:10:14.648: W/System.err(3931): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.IrishSign.app.Aa
01-04 19:10:14.648: W/System.err(3931):     ... 17 more
01-04 19:10:14.658: W/System.err(3931): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.IrishSign.app.Aa in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.IrishSign.app-1.apk]
01-04 19:10:14.658: W/System.err(3931):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-04 19:10:14.668: W/System.err(3931):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-04 19:10:14.668: W/System.err(3931):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-04 19:10:14.668: W/System.err(3931):     ... 17 more
```

Comment: What is the error? And i suppose you have activities called Aa, Bb, Cc, etc. did you register them as activities in you manifest?

Comment: I'm supposing the 'selectedClass' is an Activity class... have you added those other Activity classes in your manifest.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Define all the activities in you Manifest file like this:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"></activity>
```

Include the . in front of the name. Place this within the Application tags.